# Designing an Opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

This seems like a simple question but here is what I have so far:

**For number 1** I said it is impossible b/c Vout/Vin = 1 + R1/R2 in which case you cannot have an attenuating amplifer it is not possible

**But for number 2** I am a bit confused b/c if I derive the Vout/Vin expression for a simple inverting amplifier I get the answer that it should be able to attenuate the input signal b/c Vout/Vin = -Rf/Ri along those lines.

But the hw also says the sensor cannot provide any current???????
so does that mean I cannot assume what I did which is just deriving an expression for Vout/vin for a simple inverting op amp? Is there other factors that I should consider?

**For question 3**. I was thinking of just designing a simple inverting op amp with the resistor ratio that matches the factor of 2.5.

Can someone help me with this problems. I feel like it is very simple but I really lack the fundamentals.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: (1) Well, you can always have a resistive divider buffered by a op-amp voltage follower. I think that might count as an attenuating amplifier. (2) When it says the sensor cannot provide current, it means that the sensor has a very high impedance output which means whatever it feeds must have an even higher input impedance. That probably means you cannot use a non-inverting amp since there are resistors in the feedback path unless use VERY VERY large feedback resistors. A non-inverting amp does not have this problem. It may also mean you need to use an instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: (3) Why are you so focused on the inverting amp? There is the non-inverting amp as well.

Also, if you try what I said in (1) you will run into the impedance problem of (2) since there are resistors in the feedback path.

Comment: @Toor I assumed it would only attenuate for the inverting amp but I honestly wasnt sure about (1) as well. Also gain is 1+ Rf/Ri for non inverting

Comment: You're right that you can't amplify with a non-inverting amp. I forgot about that since I have never needed to attenuate a high impedance source. Since you need to attenuate with a high source output impedance, the question might just be wanting you to use very veyr large feedback resistors in an inverting amp configuration that attenuates. Like...megaohm or gigaohm resistors.  In reality, this is tricky since more current can leak across the board than through the resistors so you have to be careful when laying out and building the circuit and keep it clean. But your HW is on paper.

Comment: "No current" means that the sensor must be connected to one of the opamp's inputs (which are assumed to have infinite impedance), and not to anything else where current might flow (such as a feedback network, even with very high resistors). So it looks as if the question's constraints rule out 2.

Comment: There is a solution for 3., but you are supposed to design it yourself. Do you already know about things like voltage followers, and resistor voltage dividers?

Comment: You are not allowed to draw any current from the sensor. And you don't need any gain. So don't use the Opamp to provide gain. But use an Opamp.